# Paginação sob demanda com botão e método POST em PHP utlizando PDO

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

Olhei alguns sites e vi algumas coisas sobre isso, mas eu não estou conseguindo entender a lógica por trás da página sob demanda.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#btnpaginas').click(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "paginacao.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function(data)
                {
                                $(".paginacao").html(data);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });

<button id="btnpaginas">Carregar mais</button>
```

PHP

```
$inicio = 5;

$stmt = $conecta->prepare("select * from postagem order by idpost desc limit $inicio " );
    $stmt->execute();
```

Eu sei que estou fazendo errado. Ele já começa com 1 registro e quando aperto o botão "carregar mais" ele mostra o primeiro registro, que já tinha, e mais quatro. Só que com esse código que eu fiz, ele não vai carregar mais 5 se eu clicar novamente, quero saber como faço para sempre que clicar no botão, ele mostrar mais 5 registros para o meu sistema de postagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema é no entendimento do SQL, mais especificamente sobre a cláusula "LIMIT". Veja seu funcionamento no link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Para funcionar da forma como você precisa, faça o seguinte:

1) na sua página, defina uma variável **"PAGINA"** que irá guardar o número da página que você deseja obter os resultados. 
Os primeiros resultados, corresponde a página 0 "zero". A cada vez que clicar no botão CARREGAR MAIS incremente a variável **"PAGINA"**

2) sempre que fizer uma requisição para o servidor, envie número da página

Para entender a técnica que eu descrevo, acesse o link: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/entendendo-a-paginacao-de-registros-no-mysql

---

### # Código

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var pagina = 0;
jQuery('#btnpaginas').click(function(){
    pagina++;
    var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "paginacao.php?pagina="+pagina,
        data: dados,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $(".paginacao").html(data);

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$itensPorPagina = 10;
$pagina = ( !isset( $_GET['pagina'] ) ? 0 : ((int)$_GET['pagina']) - 1);
$inicio = $pagina * $itensPorPagina;


$stmt = $conecta->prepare("SELECT * FROM postagem ORDER BY idpost DESC LIMIT $inicio, $itensPorPagina " );
$stmt->execute();
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Opa, ajudou bastante! Fiz algumas alterações no PHP, mas funcionou o que eu queria. Valeu pela ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 1):

1. Código HTML/JS

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#btnpaginas').click(function(){
       var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
       jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "teste.php",
           data: dados,
           success: function(data)
           {
                           $(".paginacao").html(data);
           }
       });

       return false;
       });
   });
   </script>

   <button id="btnpaginas">Carregar mais</button>

   <div class="paginacao"></div>
   ```
2. Código PHP

   ```
   <?php 

   $numPaginas = 5;

   $stmt = $conecta->prepare("select * from postagem order by idpost desc limit $numPaginas " );
   echo $stmt->execute();
   ```

Comment: Lendro, a ideia é que ao clicar no botão "carregar mais" automaticamente apareçam mais 5 postagens abaixo das que já existem. É um site onde terão muitas pessoas fazendo muitas postagens, como se fosse o facebook, mas sem scroll automático. Pelo que eu vi esse código que você colocou só vai mostrar até 5 postagens no máximo. A ideia é não usar o select nesse caso. Tem alguma outra ideia?

Comment: Desculpe, depois do seu comentário eu percebi que eu entendi errado sua pergunta. Eu editei a resposta, mas não vai adiantar muito. 

Quando a pessoa clicar no botão, vai ser feita uma requisição pro seu arquivo .php, no arquivo vai ser feita uma query e você vai devolver o resultado dessa query pro seu arquivo html, e você tem que tratar o resultado da query dentro da função `success()`, muito provavelmente vai ser recebido um `array` e o ideal é tratar isso com um `foreach`.